# Python: merge two lists of dictionaries where one dictionary has a unique column

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries:

```
l1 = [{'a': 'mike', '4/22/20': 10}, {'b': 'bob', '4/22/20': 5}]
l2 = [{'a': 'mike', 'pop': 40, '4/22/20': 1}, {'b': 'bob', 'pop': 30, '4/22/20': 1}]
```

I want to combine theses into a single list formatted like:

```
cl = [{'a': 'mike', 'pop': 40', '4/22/20': [10,1]}, {'b': 'bob', 'pop': 30, '4/22/20': [5,1]}]
```

I have looked at many related solutions but can't quite get anything I've tried to work. Any nudges would be appreciated.

update for alternate formatting, gathering time series into it's only dictionary key:

```
l1 = [{'a': 'mike', '4/22/20': 10, '4/23/20': 11}, {'b': 'bob', '4/22/20': 5, '4/23/20': 9}]
l2 = [{'a': 'mike', 'pop': 40, '4/22/20': 1, '4/23/20': 1}, {'b': 'bob', 'pop': 30, '4/22/20': 1, '4/23/20': 2}]
```

resulting in:

```
cl = [{'a': 'mike', 'pop': 40', 'time_data': {'4/22/20': [10,1], '4/23/20': [11,1]}}, {'b': 'bob', 'pop': 30, 'time_data': {'4/22/20': [5,1], '4/23/20': [9,2]}}]
```

I do want do deduplicate every field except the date key/values, I need them both even if they are the same value.

Comment: What's your key supposed to be for `d1`? => {"key": {"a": "mike" ...}

Comment: yeah, late night brain cramp, I meant to format that as a list of dictionaries. Updated.

Comment: Been there, don't sweat it. I'll post an answer around 8 hours from now. Hopefully it will help. Talk soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is a list not dict

```
def merge(d1, d2):
  for k in set(d1+d2):
    if k in d1:
      v1 = d1[k]
      if k in d2:
        v2 = d2[k]
        yield k, (v1 if v1 == v2 else [v1, v2])
      else:
        yield k, v1
    else:
      yield k, d2[k]
[dict(merge(d1, d2)) for d1, d2 in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Comment: that was very helpful, thank you. I'm on 3.8 and had to change d1+d2 to {**d1, **d2} to make it work, and I also had some columns where I wanted both values even if they were the same, but now I have what I need in the form I need it. I will study this solution for a while.

Comment: assuming I have multiple dates in that data and want all date keys per dictionary instead of being standalone to be in "time_series": [{'4/22/20': [0, 0]},{'4/23/20': [1,0]}], would I reorganize that after the merge, or can that be done here as well?

Comment: An example of input and needed output will be helpful.

Comment: Separating date keys can be combined with a separate run like
```
for k, v in d.items():
   if re.fullmatch(r'\d\d?/\d\d?/\d\d?', k):   # Check if the key looks like a date
     d.pop(k)
     d.setdefault('time_delta', []).append(v)